# VSCode Xdebug PHP for Magento 2 - How to set breakpoints?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, magento2, centos7, xdebug

Is anyone using VSCode for developing in Magento? I have been using it for years for other languages, thus I found convenient to adopt it for Magento too.

However, I am not able to make it running. I followed all the steps recommended, but it did not worked:

```
yum install php-devel
yum install php-pear
yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake
pecl install xdebug-3.1.5
```

Add it to `/etc/php.ini`:

```ini
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

```
chmod +x /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
service httpd restart
```

I've installed Xdebug extension and launched the `.json` file for attaching the session:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9003
    }
```

When I open Magento, the breakpoint is never met and stopped. Why?

Comment: A few general starting points: 1) *"pecl install xdebug-3.1.5", "xdebug.remote_enable = 1"* -- Please go through https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide first. You are trying to use Xdebug **v2** params for Xdebug **v3**. 2) You can then also check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 3) Ensure that Xdebug is enabled and configured. You can use `xdebug_info();` output to see the actual/live config as well as Xdebug log to see what is happening when debug session gets initiated (if it gets initiated ofc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the following to setting to the php.ini.

xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes